# Searching for "Windows Printer Interceptor"

Tags: windows, printing, driver

I'm searching for a way to send printed documents directly to our Document Management System (DMS). My idea is some kind of "printer interceptor" that catches all the data thats gonna to be send to the printer from application, sends it to my DMS and forwards the printer data to the estimated printer.

That interceptor should worl for any printer. So it could be something thats added directly to spool manager.
Another idea is that interceptor could be a selectable printer from the printer-selectbox of windows-applications. That interceptor-printer itself is configured to redirect the data to another printer-driver.

Does there already exist anything, that I can use, or do I have to write a printer driver from scratch? Is my idea possible at all?

Regards,
Michael

In addition: Where possible I want to store plain text not an image. So I need my interceptor to work before all data is transformed to printer-control-signals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.all2pdf.com/virtual-printer-driver-uni.htm

Answer (score 0):

@mibutec this popular solution could directly call your DMS: http://www.printandshare.info